# Creating a function to iterate over tibble elements within a large list in R

Tags: r, function, xts

I am trying to create a function to automatize some basic formatting I need to do before I combine multiple datasets into an xts. I can do a bulk read of the files and create a large list of tibbles. But I'm having a hard time creating a function to iterate over that list. When I read individual files into a df, I have been running the following:

`df<-df[!(duplicated(df$DateTime)),]
 dfx<-xts(df[,-1], order.by = as.POSIXct(df$DateTime, format="%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S"))`

Then I do an merge.xts of all of the 'dfx' objects. One issue I have with the data is that the DateTime does not always match up between files and the above method gives me a large xts with NAs, which is what I prefer to another type of merge/rbind. I would like to create a function to do this over and over, especially because reading each file into separate data frames and then merging is grueling now that I have to combine 10+. All of my attempts have not been successful and now I am just stuck. :/ Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `merge.zoo` supports multiway merges so if `L` is a list of the data frames and the index is always called `DateTime` then: `as.xts(do.call("merge", lapply(L, read.zoo, index = "DateTime", tz = "", format = "%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a `list`, we can use `lapply` to loop over the `list` and use an anonymous function call to apply the function

```
lst2 <- lapply(lst1, function(df) {
     df<-df[!(duplicated(df$DateTime)),]
     xts(df[,-1], order.by = as.POSIXct(df$DateTime, format="%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S")) 
  })
```

and then use `Reduce` to do the `merge`

```
Reduce(merge, lst2)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was making it much more complicated than it needed to be.